# What to use in iOS as a drop down list

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I'm playing around with RubyMotion and trying to add a simple list to an sample app. In the list there will be four items (`say, milk, cheese, beer, water`) out of which the user should be able to pick (select) one.

What control can I use for this purpose?

Comment: You can use a popOverController with tableView or an ActionSheet ?

Comment: For that you should use a picker since there are not many elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want UIPickerView.

Here are some Tutorial for that:

- [A Tutorial on Making a UIPickerView Sample App](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/A-Tutorial-on-Making-a-UIPickerView-Sample-App)
- [UIPickerView Example](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html)